# Location of NodeJS standard library

Tags: node.js

Can someone please help me find the location of standard NodeJS modules like `http` or `fs`?

When I write:

```js
const http = require('http');
```

Where is the module coming from? For NPM this is easy to find, but strangely I can't find `http.js` or any other standard library file.

Answer (score 1):

Well this depends on which operating system you are using:

If you are on windows it's in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules` or at least I think...

If you want to know on linux check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189230/what-is-the-location-of-node-modules) on the askubuntu.com website. In this question, someone answered that it was in

> /usr/local/lib/node or /usr/local/lib/node_modules

- Tejas Lotlikar

There is a high chance that on mac, the location is the same as linux because macOS is based upon some "ancient" linux dist.

EDIT : If you have a custom installation path then (of course) nodeJS is in the folder you unpacked it. You can also check your user/system variables aka environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

The actual running node location can be found with this command

`node -e "console.log(process.execPath)"`

this will output the executed bin compiled nodejs path. which will not really much help you.

what will help you is knowing the node version you are running and check the source code of the module you want. [http.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/http.js) .

**or** debug nodejs in real time.
break point on the http module and then get into the module itself with the help of the debugger. check out [this guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike third-party dependencies Nodejs built-in modules like http or fs are bundled with the node binary that you have installed. This has to do with optimization so that they run faster.

One way to find them is in the source code of Node. You can go to the node official repo and find `http` and `fs` under the [`lib`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/main/lib) directory.